# How to delete a doc at a specific shard in Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I want to delete a specific doc at a specific shard in Solr, below is my query:

`http://localhost:8080/solr/collections_1_replica1/update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:1</query></delete>&commit=true&distrib=false`

But this still effect to `collections_2_replica1`, so what is the correct query in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Tyr out this one :

```
curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/collection_name/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>id:1</query></delete>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default Solr Cloud collection configurations, Solr choose where to put the document according to the document id (docId.hash() % number of shards).

In other words, you're not supposed to delete from a specific shard because you can't be sure whether the document is there or on the other shards.

If I'm not wrong, the distrib=false parameter is not effective in updated.